# Filter the collections and remove a collection eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to remove a filtered collection from a collections like I have this returned collections.

```
$products = items::where('item_id',$request->item_id)->with('product_reviews')->with('product_reviews.profile')->get();
foreach($products->product_reviews as $r):
    if($r->status==='unapproved'):
        //remove this from 'products' collections because its not approved yet
        $this->remove($this);
    endif;
endforeach;
```

but this

```
$this->remove($this);
```

does not work, neither a valid syntax to remove the collection, I just don't know how to remove the filtered collection e.g. if column status contains 'unapproved'. Any ideas, help please?

Comment: Why don't you include another where considering the status?

Comment: Can you post an example base on my given code snippet please?

Comment: I don't know how to do it as I'm targeting the product_reviews which belong to the items model.

Comment: you have an unnecessary `'` after `->item_id` probably a typo?

Comment: @VishalSharma: ow my bad, a wrong typo, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition in your relation. This is not tested but most likely will solve your problem.

```
items::where('item_id',$request->item_id)->with([
   'product_reviews' => function ($query) {
       $query->where('status', 'approved')->with('profile');
    }
])->get();
```

Comment: perfect! pleasure.

Comment: ah my bad, it does not work unfortunately :( my bad I have a 'if' statement in my blade where only display only if the status is approved that why I thought it worked but it was due to the if statement on my blade

Comment: Can you show the output of the above query? Is it giving you an error? how many states `status` can have? `approved` and `unapproved`?

Comment: Does not show any error but the 'unapproved' reviews is still included and not filtered.

Comment: how many states `status` can have? `approved` and `unapproved`?

Comment: Only 'approved' and 'unapproved' states

Comment: Please see my updated post, I have added 'product_reviews.profile' as one 'product_reviews' have one 'profile'.

Comment: I have remove the 'product_reviews.profile' and seem's its working, there's no 'unapproved' collection when I 'var_dump' any ideas, help please? I don't want to sacrifice 'product_reviews.profile' by removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. a little bit strange since the other 2 solutions should work for your case.

Have you tried to filter and pass the objects to other array and show them inside your view? Like:

```
$productWithReviews = items::where('item_id',$request->item_id)->with('product_reviews')->get();
$products = [];
foreach($productWithReviews->product_reviews as $r):
    if($r->status!=='unapproved'):
        $products[] = $r;
    endif;
endforeach;
```